# How to change the background image of a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style

How can I change my `textarea` background image when I select a value from the `select` menu?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>  Your Title  </title>

<script>
function kool()
{
`enter code here`abc.style.background="img1.bmp"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea name="abc">
1) Make paper airplanes out of the exam. Aim them at the instructor's left nostril. 
2) Bring cheerleaders during an exam.
</textarea>

<select id="xyz" onchange="kool()">
<option value="A">Image 1</option>
<option value="B">Image 2</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<textarea id="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
</textarea>

<select onchange="document.getElementById('text').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.value + ')';">
<option value="image1.png">Image 1</option>
<option value="image2.png">Image 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: in this where do i specify path to my image ?? 

<select onchange="document.getElementById('text').style.backgroundImage = 'url('img1.bmp + this.value + ')';">

Comment: In the `value=""` for the `<option />`!

Comment: in your code how do i trace my textarea, i mean my textarea is actually in a iframe

Comment: i gave +1 too, how to set my textarea path

Comment: @sAc Thanks ;)
@subanki How do you mean 'set my textarea path' and 'trace my textarea'? You can get your textarea in JavaScript using `document.getElementById('text')`.

Comment: my textarea is in a <iframe name= "dork">

Comment: Your textarea is INSIDE the `iframe`? Try this: `window.frames['dork'].getElementById('id').style.etc`, replace `id` with the actual `id` attribute of the `textarea` inside the `iframe`.

Comment: dont worry i figured it out already , thanx buddy i am adding ur name also in my credit page, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<script>
function kool(input)
{
   var el = document.getElementById('abc');
   el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + input + ')';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea name="abc" id="abc">
1) Make paper airplanes out of the exam. Aim them at the instructor's left nostril. 
2) Bring cheerleaders during an exam.
</textarea>

<select id="xyz" onchange="kool(this.value)">
<option value="A.jpg">Image 1</option>
<option value="B.jpg">Image 2</option>
</select>
```

Make sure that paths are correct.

Comment: `url()` isn't a JavaScript function, so that won't work ;)

(Edited it for ya)